# How to remove post date osclass

Tags: osclass

Have problem, it's simple but not for me)

How to remove post date? I found what I need to delete in the theme file here is this piece of code

/oc-content/themes/tuffclassified/item.php

```
osc_item_pub_date()
```

i delete it. The date was deleted but not on the main page.

So how remove post date on main page?

Comment: Please add more codes.

Answer (score 0):

This code need to remove in file ad-loop-premium.php for 'premium' posts

```
<strong><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-fw"></i><?php echo osc_format_date(osc_premium_pub_date()); ?></strong>
```

This for simple ads.
item.php - in file

```
osc_item_pub_date()
```